# Magento - how to display email to a friend form in View phtml file

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When you click 'Email to a Friend' you will be directed to a form to submit. I want to display this form in the product view page instead of 'Email to a friend' link. How it is possible to call send.phtml template in view.phtml?
I tried by giving this

```
<?php 
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("core/template")->setTemplate("sendfriend/send.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

But this didn't work,displayed an error. Please help

Answer (score 0):

use this you were missing the `block type`

```
<?php 
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("sendfriend/send")->setTemplate("sendfriend/send.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried in this method.But it didn't work. Its been few days that I am stuck up with this part.. :(

Comment: disabled the cache and refresh the cache too and also check the error log for errors.

Comment: Yes, I rechecked by disabling the cache and refreshing but still no luck..Also no errors are shown

Comment: did the module is enable and and send to email to friend is showing?

Comment: Hi @BridgitThomas i think you are getting error of Cookie Instance so try with to go System->Configuratoin->Catalog->Email to a Friend in that  there is Email templates Tab,     "Set Limit Sending By"  Cookie(Unsafe) to "IP Address."

Comment: From admin side Send to Email Friend is enable and also "Limit Sending By" was set as Cookie(Unsafe), this I have changed to IP address. Still no luck.

Comment: Yes you are right but set "Limit Sending By" as "IP Address".

Comment: Also suppose if I try by clicking the link Email to a Friend link.It directs me to the page but not showing the form i.e i get a blank page.Why so? :(

Comment: @PHP Weblineindia - I have set as IP Address. STill no luck

Comment: is there any error in var/report ? or any log for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95649/discussion-between-php-weblineindia-and-bridgit-thomas).